# My identity is exposed on a forum when using tor

Tags: anonymity

My friend was trolling on a forum and now he got banned.
Now they banned my new account too.
I tried to use Tor, I disabled scripts-But it doesn't help, They can still detect my computer.
What else do i have to do?
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

1. Quit trolling
2. The forum owners may have decided to block all Tor users, or certain exit nodes.
3. The forum owners may be  blocking Tor users with a specific browser/OS profile.
4. See point 1, this is a poor use of Tor.

Comment: +1 this is a classic "so, asking for a friend..." kinda question.